# Create trigger to Audit data changes SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

Good night folks,

I need to create a stored Procedure that giving the name of a table by parameter create a trigger to Audit data changes in the table.

I need to do something very similar to the code of this article, but for performance, reasons I need to have a Form in my program that allows me to choose the tables and the main fields to audit.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database

I have tried changing the code in various ways with cursors etc unsuccessful because I have not much experience with T-SQL.

My main doubt is how to give the table name and the fields that I want (which can be 2 or 3 or more) by parameter in my stored procedure.

```
Select field = 0,maxfield = max (ORDINAL_POSITION) 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME =tablename 

while field <maxfield 
begin 
    select field = min (ORDINAL_POSITION) 
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where TABLE_NAME =tablename 
      and ORDINAL_POSITION> @ field 

    select bit = (field - 1)% 8 + 1 =bit select power (2, @ bit - 1) 
    select char = ((field - 1) / 8) + 1 if substring (COLUMNS_UPDATED () , @ char, 1) &bit> 0 or type in ('I', 'D')
```

I need something like:

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = tablename 
  and COLUMN_NAME = 'My FIELD'
```

I will be very grateful if you can help me, because I am trying to change the code almost for two days without much success.

Comment: Table name should be easy.  if you take what the link already does for you, you can leave off the `SELECT  @TABLE_NAME = MIN(TABLE_NAME)` and `WHILE @TABLE_NAME IS NOT NULL` loop and just set the value of `@TABLE_NAME` yourself..

Comment: Thank you for your help, but my big problem is with the field names. what I have now, is a form where I choose the table names and fields I want Audit and store this in one table. I need make one select at this table and create on trigger By Stored Procedure in all the tables I previously chosen.

Comment: Make sure you take the appropriate steps to prevent sql injection... maybe encasing your param values using `QUOTENAME()` wherever possible will help some.

Comment: Honestly, you want to audit every column change in a audit trigger, I guarantee you will need the history of one of those not so major columns someday. Unless you are running thousands of changes per minute, performance should not be a problem.  The nice part about auditing as the link did it is that every audit table had the exact same structure which makes it much easier to get data out of the audit tables when you need it . In fact his solution is very like what we have successfully run on our multi-million record tables for well over 15 years now with no performance problem.

Comment: I'm doing an desktop application in WPF so no problem with sql injection

Comment: Well HLGEM in fact, I do not need an audit system. I am doing a CRM where our Sales managers can change prices for example, but the manager need approve that proposed changes. Therefore, it is like and audit, but just for some fields where if the managers do not agree with the changes they can revert that.